# How to access supportFragmentManager in a react native expo module

Tags: react-native, expo, expo-module

I'm trying to create a native view using expo modules, and need to use fragments. How can I access
`supportFragmentManager` to make transactions inside the view.

I've tried casting `appContext.activityProvider?.currentActivity` to `AppCompatActivity` but the resulting `supportFragmentManager` cannot find views. It shows this Error ;

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4b0 (unknown) for fragment           MapFragment{551d49} (f2a671be-f63c-4546-ad0b-8ce75b5e3697 id=0x4b0)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:513)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1840)        androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:175)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1701)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$4.run(FragmentManager.java:488)
android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: I'm having this same problem, did you find a solution that you can share?